# Do hot water storage tanks stratify naturally?

Tags: thermodynamics

Assuming we don't neglect natural convection and heat losses in the tank. Also, water is not being extracted from the tank except under the condition that a re-circulation pump activates. That's what I mean by steady state. No hot water demand.

In the tank I am looking at, a re-circulation pump will activate and pull water from near the bottom of the tank (horizontal outlet), heat it, and inject it back into near the bottom of the tank (horizontal inlet) if near the bottom of the tank gets too cold.

I know that heat losses from the walls of the tank will create vertical columns of cold water that will drop to the bottom of the tank because of buoyancy effects (colder fluid is more dense).

I also know that 1-D models don't naturally do buoyancy, so many research articles talk about introducing non-physics based ways to model the buoyancy.

What I don't know is if heat losses from the sides of the tank actually encourages better mixing due to water flow or leads to hot water stratification as the cold water at the bottom collects and then is reheated by the re-circulation pump mentioned earlier. This would affect what kind of models I look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hot water tanks stratify normally if there is a temperature difference between outside the tank and inside the tank.

For anyone who wants further details:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X12002873

Basically, as expected, the water at the sides of the tank is colder than the water in the center of the tank (since heat leaves the hot water tank through the sides of the tank and escapes into the ambient, colder fluid outside the hot water tank. This ambient fluid is usually air). As a result, the water at the sides of the tanks drops to the bottom (since colder water is more dense) and the water in the center rises (since warm water is less dense). This naturally stratifies the hot water tank because you have hot going up from the center to replace cold going down from the sides.

Here's another source to confirm it:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X03002603

"When a hot water tank without external flow is subjected to the ambient temperature, a thermal stratification of the water is formed in the course the cooling process. Thus the cooler water accumulates at bottom while hotter water ascends to the top of the tank. This phenomenon occurs even if initially all the water inside the tank is at a uniform temperature. It is originated from the fact that, prior to releasing heat to the ambient, the tank wall cools a thin vertical layer of water adjacent to the wall. Part of this heat is then transferred by diffusion from the core of the tank. The water of the vertical layer becomes denser than its surroundings and slips towards the bottom of the tank."

Comment: Can you elaborate on how?  Currently this is a low quality answer.  You should provide _some_ information from the link at least.

Comment: @JMac Done, hope this is clearer